# Sitecore multiple goals unexpected behaviour

Tags: personalization, goals

I am facing the issue with goals, I have created multiple goals according to our requirement as below:

[image]

After that, I have assigned a goal to respective pages like Ciaz goal on Ciaz page, Baleno Goal to Baleno page, etc.

Now I am to changing `datasource` rendering on a different page on bases of goal triggering or page visit on which i have assigned a goal. I have created 4 different data source and assigned `personalization rule` on rendering as below:

[image]

Now first time `personlization rule` is working fine. When i visit another car page then `datasource` should be change on bases of goal condition but its not changing. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you've set it up like this, once you trigger ANY of your goals - that's the one that will be selected. Personalisation works through conditions until it finds one that matches.

So if you have goals A and B; and personalisation going "if A then => datasource", "if B then => datasource" - and BOTH goals A and B have been triggered, only A will be selected as a datasource.

You need to rethink your personalisation strategy; Sitecore isn't laid out to do what you're asking for here.